# Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS - errors during booting - nouveau

Tags: ubuntu, nouveau

I want to install Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS from a usb stick but during booting I get the following errors: https://ibb.co/kopx1R

```
 fifo: read fault at ...engine 1f nouveau write fault
 HOST_CPU_NB REGION_VIOLATION on channel 1
 ...reason 0d gr init failed, -110
```

There is something wrong with nouveau. I have GeForce 970 GTX but some time ago I have installed Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS without problems. How to fix that ?

Comment: Does your laptop boots fine after these error?

Comment: Yes, I use Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS with nvidia proprietary drivers 384.90, but I haven't had any problems during installing Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS from the usb stick. I guess that Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS has older nouveau drivers which works fine with GeForce 970 GTX.

Comment: `nouveau` usually has these issue but it only appears during boot. At somepoint you will face problems with proprietary drivers. So, i will advice you to be with nouveau, those error doesn't effect anything.

Answer (score 0):

Boot from your USB when the grub menu appears press <kbd>e</kbd> to edit the boot option , locate  `quiet splash` and change it to :

```
nouveau.blacklist=1 quiet splash
```

Comment: Which graphics driver will be used after blacklisting nouveau ???

Comment: I believe this workaround is just to disable the logs from `nouveau`